# GeoLocation HTML5 return position.coords outside scope of getCurrentLocation

Tags: html, geolocation

I searching to return the position.coords outside the scope of the function navigator.geolocation.getCurrentLocation(getLocation,err). I have tried using window vars but i'm not able, all values are always locals. Can someone point the way. Thanks

Comment: for the correct answer see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935059/saving-variables-outside-of-navigator-geolocation-getcurrentposition-javascrip

Answer (score -1):

I assume you mean `getCurrentPosition`. If you just need the coordinates, you can do this.

```
return coords.clone();
```

**Update**

`getCurrentPosition` requires a callback function. You can use it something like this:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
    alert(pos.coords.latitude+","+pos.coords.longitude);
});
```

Comment: Assuming that getCurrentPosition(getLocation) is returning the function getLocation(position){return coords.clone();}, the result is NULL for coords=navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getLocation); Advice.

Comment: The result should be null. You need to provide a callback function to `getCurrentPosition`, it does not return the coordinates.