# Saving variables outside of navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, geolocation, navigator, w3c-geolocation

I'm trying to play with the scope of js to pull a variable out of navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition

```
var lat;
function callback (position) {
    lat = position.coords.latitude;
}
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(callback,fail,{timeout:10000});
// after getCurrentPosition succeeds
alert(lat); // this alerts null
```

The above code cannot store position.coords.latitude in the lat variable because of the scope.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remember the async\ajax nature.

this is the execution order of your code:

```
var lat;
alert(lat); // this alerts null
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(callback,fail,{timeout:10000});
function callback (position) {
    lat = position.coords.latitude;
}
```

This why you get null. **async!**, **async!** :)

Comment: I see, so position.coords.latitude is indeed stored in lat?  If so when, how can I transfer the data in lat to another variable?

Comment: @Derek. you call other function from `callback` wih the `lat` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can save your Position variable to input hidden field on document ready. After that, you can use jQuery to get back Geolocation value

Javscript:

```
<script>
var lat;
alert(lat); // this alerts null
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(callback,fail,{timeout:10000});
function callback (position) {
    jQuery('#pos_lat').val(position.coords.latitude);
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
    <input hidden id='pos_lat' value='' /> 
    //value = position latitude on load
```

To get back value:

```
jQuery('#pos_lat').val();
```

Comment: To set `localStorage.setItem("pos_lat",position.coords.latitude);`  to get `localStorage.getItem("pos_lat");`